# Initialisation of a vector of object

Tags: c++, object, vector, initialization

How can I initialise a vector with objects?

I have tried:

```
set<CardSet> empty;
vector< vector< vector< set<CardSet> > > > range_table( 10, vector<vector<CardSet> >( 10, vector<CardSet> ( 10, empty) ) );
```

Ps: I didn't found the answer maybe because I do not have the keywords: So if you know what I should search feel free to tell me.

the correct lines are:
    set vide;
    vector< vector< vector< set > > > tableau_des_ranges( 10, vector > >( 10, vector > ( 10, vide) ) );

I do not believe that someone else will use it  maybe to see a triple vector ^^

thank you very much and sorry for this question

Comment: `vector< vector< vector< set` looks *very* suspicious. Is there really a need for such a deeply nested data structure?

Comment: I want to do it for all the player of a table (10) for all moment of a hand (preflop flop turn river), for all action (check bet raise etc...) and the data is all the possible hand, a hand is a CardSet (2 cards) all possible hands are a Set of CardSet. I agree that it is not so comfortable :s

Comment: I cannot help you with a design issue in the comments section (and with only this information); but if you have a (statically) fixed amount of entries, a `vector` is not the appropriate data structure. Also, consider wrapping those vectors into classes that provide specialized and convenient interfaces.

Comment: Create objects is too much ambitious for me now :). For the moment I am learning how to use existing objects, make small changes... I will keep in mind your remark for when I will be older :) I believe this way reduce the consumption of headaches painkiller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type declaration has the type in the inner vector as `set<CardSet>`, while the temporaries used to initialise the vectors have it as just `CardSet`. One of these is wrong.